# Changing paths when reloadOnSearch = false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In my Angular app, some routes have `reloadOnSearch` set to false so that [Bootstrap tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) work ok.

The problem comes when a link in one of those views links to another of those views. Links just don't work, because the controller does not reload the view.

So I have to use `ng-click` on those links.

```
$scope.goToThisPage = function () {
  $location.path(newPage);
  $route.reload();
};
```

However, that does not work and always takes me to the default routing. Same happens if I replace the last line of the function with `$scope.$apply()`.

What is the best way to move between routes that have `reloadOnSearch` set to false?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a separate controller for each of those tabs?

As far as I know, `reloadOnSearch: false` will only prevent the controller from reloading if a query parameter or hash in the url changes. So, moving between `/route/page?param=1` and `/route/page?param=2` will not reload the controller, but moving to `/route/anotherpage` definitely should.

I don't understand entirely how you're getting this issue, but for what it's worth, this is how I've solved reloadOnSearch issues when I having a single controller. Even though the controller and view don't reload when a search parameter changes, `$location` still does, so I would just listen to `$locationChangeSuccess` in the controller and make any changes to bound scope variables in the callback.

**Edit**

Looking at the documentation for tabs, wouldn't it be possible for you to just not use links to switch the tabs, and instead call the `.tab("show")` method using `ng-click`?